# problem with cron job for every 2 minutes

Tags: cron

I have a cron job for very 2 min and somebody told me that some servers do not allow 2 min cron jobs. basically from 30 min. it is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not true. The minimal step is one minute. But depend of service you want to run. Please share more details

Comment: I'm working on a product for users so users may use any kind of services , that we do not know, ! that is why i'm asking you bro

Comment: the step is one minute. But you may have services (as jboss for eample) which will start for several minutes. So you should educate users :)