# How to schedule cronjob for every 45 days?

Tags: cron

How to execute a shell script via a cronjob every 45 days?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8699075/8239155

Comment: Possible duplicate of [problem with cron job for every 2 minutes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201937/problem-with-cron-job-for-every-2-minutes)

Comment: See my `systemd`  based solution, if you are using a distribution with this init/service system

Comment: @vfbsilva which answer in that post would solve the 45-day question here?

Comment: @JeffSchaller third answer explains the meaning of each field and syntax

Comment: @vfbsilva there *was* a second answer over there that linked to a commercial website that explained the fields, yes. So would the man pages. But neither explains how you'd use cron to set up a 45-day schedule.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't need exactly 45 days, but "one and a half months" will do, then a straightforward method would be to run at the beginning of the month every three months, and at the middle of the next month after each of those:

```
0 12  1 1,4,7,10  * /path/to/script
0 12 16 2,5,8,11  * /path/to/script
```

For general arbitrary intervals, the other answers are obviously better, but 45 days sounds like it's based on the length of a month anyway. Human users might also be more used to something happening in the beginning or the middle of a month, instead of seeing the exact date drift a day or two each time.

Answer (score 9):

Since cron doesn't support a simple, direct translation of that requirement, I would approach it with a timestamp file and a daily cron job:

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/wrapper/script/below.sh
```

the wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash
timestampfile=/var/run/this-job/timetampfile

# exit now if it hasn't been 45 days
(( 
  $(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Z "$timestampfile") 
            < 
  (45 * 24 * 60 * 60) 
)) && exit 0

touch "$timestampfile"
: run real script here
```

This runs several risks:

- someone deleting the timestamp file
- someone touching the timestamp file (for better or for worse)
- leaving it non-obvious from the cron job entry that the actual script runs every 45 days

Comment: Alternatively, invert the condition so the main branch of the `if` can `exit` the script when it's not going to do anything. That'll make it easier to stick the test to the script itself.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, @ilkkachu; thank you! I've incorporated it.

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699075/how-to-set-cron-job-for-every-45-days), you could accomplish this with the following syntax:

```
00 12 * * *  test $(( $(date +\%s)/24/60/60\%45 )) = 20 && your_script
```

This job will run every day at noon.  It then calculates the modulo of the number of days from epoch and tests if it is equal to the modulo you specify.  In this case I have specified 20 which would make it evaluate to true for today (2018-05-09 in between 00:00 GMT and 23:59 GMT), then 45 days from today, etc.  You can calculate/test with the following:

```
$ echo $(( $(date +%s)/24/60/60%45 ))
20
$ echo $(( $(date -d '+45 days' +%s)/24/60/60%45 ))
20
$ echo $(( $(date -d '+44 days' +%s)/24/60/60%45 ))
19
```

(beware that if you're not in a UTC timezone, you may have to take the hour of the day into account).

Answer (score 4):

**Alternative solution:** `systemd` is eating all parts of the Linux system. With this in mind, it now has a `timer` unit that can be related to a `service` unit of the same name to create a schedule and mimic anacron. Example:

Service. We will call it `foo` and it will run your script `/home/user/foo.sh`. When working with timers your `service` unit does not need to have the `[Install]` section:

```
/etc/systemd/system/foo.service

[Unit]
Description=My foo script

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/user/foo.sh
```

Timer. This is the special unit that will handle time schedule:

```
/etc/systemd/system/foo.timer

[Unit]
Description=Run foo every 45 days and on boot
Persistent=true

[Timer]
OnBootSec=15min
OnUnitActiveSec=45d 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Taking a look at the `[Timer]` section, your script will run 15 minutes after boot(you can remove this), and each 45 days. The `Persistent=` parameter means that even after rebooting the schedule will persist to disk and not be restarted.

And then, enable both units:

```
systemctl enable foo.service
systemctl enable foo.timer
```

You may not like `systemd`, but this is a quick solution to problems with schedule and `cron`.

**Further Reading:**

- [systemd - Timer units that mimic anacron behaviour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84858/34720)
- [systemd/Timers - Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers)

Comment: With your average Linux box having to reboot every other week or so to apply kernel/libc/... security updates, that is very unlikely to have that script run every 45 days.

Comment: I agree, and that's why i used the `Persistent=` parameter on my answer. Not everyone do live kernel patching(neither have the resources to pay such tools), to make servers "rebootless".

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue trying to publish a `crl` using `OpenBSD 6.6`. Used the following script which schedules it's next launch first thing.

```
#!/bin/sh

# copy current crontab to file without launching script    
/usr/bin/crontab -l | grep -v "/var/publishCRL.sh" > /var/tmpCron

# add entry for 45 days from now
# 45 days = 3888000 seconds
/bin/echo $(date -j -r `expr $(date +%s) + 3888000` "+%M %H %d %m")" * /var/publishCRL.sh" >> /var/tmpCron

# load edited crontab
/usr/bin/crontab /var/tmpCron

# cleanup
/bin/rm /var/tmpCron

# do CRL stuff
```