# Why does my vixie cron entry to run every other day, actually run on consecutive days every 4th time?

Tags: linux, cron

I have an entry in my crontab file:

`14 17 * * */2 python /home/pi/scripts/irrigate_5mins.py >/dev/null 2>&1`

The intention is to run the command every other day, which is what the manpage (`man 5 crontab`) says is what `*/2` does. The actual quote from the manpage is:

> Steps are also permitted after an asterisk, so if you want to say
>   ``every two hours'', just use ``*/2''

The actual behaviour is that the command runs with a recurrence pattern of 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1 and so on. So, for example, in March / April the command ran on 15th, 17th, **18th,** 20th, 22nd, 24th, **25th**, 27th, 29th, 31st, **1st** April, 3rd, 5th, 7th, **8th**, 10th, 12th, where the dates in **bold** are those where the command was run the previous day.

So my question is: why is it behaving like this, and is there an (easy) way I can make it do what is expected?

System info:

```
root@pi:~# uname -a
Linux pi 4.9.28+ #998 Mon May 15 16:50:35 BST 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux
root@pi:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:        8.0
Codename:       jessie
```

It may or may not be of relevance that the system is connected to a timer which causes a hard reboot every 24 hours.

Comment: This is similar to [How to schedule cronjob for every 45 days?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/442792/170373), just with a different interval. Most of the solutions there apply if you just change 45 to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specifying `*/2` in the day-of-week field, you run on even days.  Even days of the week are Mondays, Wednesdays, Fridays and Sundays. (Actually, these are the odd days, hmm, still...)

If you want to run the job on slightly more regular intervals, use the day-of-month field instead (the third field).  Note that on months with an odd number of days, this will cause the job to instead *skip* one day when the next month starts:  ..., 28th, 30th, (not on the 31st, not on the 1st), 2nd, 4th, etc.

You could work around this by adding a schedule for months with even days and a separate schedule for months with an odd number of days (although I haven't really thought that through properly to know whether that would make it match up properly).

Another possibility would be to have the job schedule itself using `at` instead of using `cron`.  This would definitely be a more "hackish" solution and would possibly fail if the job terminated abnormally between starting to run and successfully rescheduling itself in two days time, or if the system happened to be down at the next scheduled run.

Comment: You'd need to separate the months based on how many odd months there are in a year preceding that month. And it would still skip when the year changes, since most years have an odd number of days

Comment: `*/2` would run on days 0,2,4,6: Sunday, Tues, Thu, Sat

Comment: @glennjackman Yes. So assuming the reported days refers to _this_ year (2018), they are a bit strange.

Comment: [Test the cron definition string here](http://cron.schlitt.info/) Just paste `14 17 * * */2` and click `test` to see a list of the next executions.

Answer (score 1):

I would schedule the cron job to run every day. Then the script can decide if the day-of-year is an even number: if not, exit.

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
doy = int(today.strftime("%j"))
if (doy % 2 == 1): exit()
...
```

Comment: Note that it would still call the script two days in a row in non-bissextile years (on the 31st of December and the day after).

Comment: True. One could use days since some point in time, or something like ((day of year mod 2 plus year mod 2) mod 2)